# The name 'Database' does not exist in the current context error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am a Java developer by profession and it's only my second day in life that I have anything to do with .net code.

I need to get an ASP.NET MVC application up and running for a demo purpose.

I installed the visual studio 2013 and imported the project.

In the project there are couple of .cshtml files which contain database related code.

After trying to build the project I am getting errors in the database code in `.cshtml` files. For example, I get an error,

> The name 'Database' does not exist in the current context

on this line of code:

```
var db = Database.Open("test");
```

After searching the net for the solution, I added reference to `WebMatrix.Data` library.

But still I am getting the same error.

If I use the above database code in the controller class it works; At least it doesn't give any compilation errors.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program will help? Do you have a working reference to database somewhere else?
In Visual Studio, if you put the cursor on "Database" and press ctrl + dot, do you get any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Jonny for the reply and link. The problem seemed to be absence of 'using' statement. After adding line '@using WebMatrix.Data' the error vanished :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be absence of 'using' statement in .cshtml file. After adding line '@using WebMatrix.Data' the error vanished.
Before posting my question here i had tried adding 'using WebMatrix.Data'.
But it turned out i was missing '@' character just before 'using' in .cshtml.